# How do I best describe a "confirm a download" in a dialog box?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, dialog, grammar

We have a feature that offers subscription-based downloads. There are limitations to the counter back-end so to make sure a customer does not get charged by mistake, we have implemented a pop up box that requires the user to confirm the download.

We are trying to stay away from the word charge, but I couldn't think of any other. Can anyone help? General critiques are welcome.

[image: confirm your dilemma]

Thanks!

Comment: if you stay with the same, make sure to change to "By confirming your download" - although possibly rephrased to change the verb from confirming to verify, or something similar?

Comment: You are absolutely right. What was I thinking? Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would keep it as a **simple message** along the lines of the Android [writing style](http://developer.android.com/design/style/writing.html) guidelines (even if it isn't for mobile):

> Download for 1 credit?
>   Download  |  Cancel

It's short, to the point, and avoids words with negative connotations.

Answer (score 2):

Since users may ignore the text in the dialog, making the button a bit more descriptive and removing/shortening body text is another option.

[Download For 1 Credit] [Cancel]

Answer (score 1):

**Confirmation dialog** should consist of a **simple confirmation question and 2 or more selectable responses**. So I would change it to be a short question instead of what it now is.

And since the download confirmation is a response to an action that the user has done (by clicking download), the user should know what he/she is doing, so keeping the question simple you make sure it's easy to answer as well.

The way **JohnGB** already put it was my first thought as well, so not providing any other suggestions of the wordings, just that confirmation dialog should be a simple question with clear answers.

*Note: If the "approve" response is critical (like it costs something when you click on it), it shouldn't be the default response for the confirmation, so you don't accidentally approve to pay.*